# Fizzler Stackoverflow Exception only IIS

Tags: iis, html-agility-pack, stack-overflow

I'm using Fizzler (HtmlAgilityPack) for parsing html in ASP.Net WebService project. Project runs successfully in Visual Studio executables, and i can debug local project step by step.
After i deploy it to IIS , it gets stackoverflow exception on Flatten operation in HTMLNodeListExtensions.cs .

Problematic query is :

> engine.Parse("#singleid .afewclass a")

This works on small sized html documents, but when this html document grows Flattening operation goes non-returning recursive operation, so stackoverlow occur. But only in IIS. (I'm using IIS 7.5 on windows 7 x64 - .net 4.0).

Is any IIS configuration that i'm missing for WebServices?
Or any Application Pool specification for solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I have get around this problem with changing engine.Parse methods with Xpath selectors. Now its working on IIS too.

Comment: You could post a solution to your problem as an answer to your question, and then accept it.